# Why 他妈的 means (swear word)

Tags: phrase

Why 他妈的 means fuck

I just started learning Chinese and kinda understood why many combinations of character means that in English but here
ˋ`ˋ<他><妈><的>`ˋ ˋ`<He><mother><target>ˋ`ˋ

Comment: As in all cultures, the position / status / virtue of one's mother is of utmost importance as it's one's mother that gave us birth and therefore life itself. So, to swear / curse another person's mother is considered the epitome of insults and humiliation. In 他妈的, it is what is left unsaid but implied which forms the insulting part. It's something like "what the ....", (WTF)

Comment: It is puzzling because the fourth character is rarely uttered.

Comment: Think of it like this, referring to another's mother disrespectfully is not good like swearing is not good similar to calling someone a mother-f*er.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

的 here doesn't mean target, it is functioning as a possessive marker that marks the subject before it possesses the object after it.

他妈的 literally means " his mother's " -- short for 'his mother's (*swearing word*)'

他妈的 is mostly used as an exclamation that expresses displeasure or anger  similar to 'damn it' in English

Answer (score 0):

It is short for `肏他妈的屄`, `to fuck his mother's cunt`. The full phrase is often considered to be too vulgar even for slang, thus the omission.

### EDIT

Interestingly the phrase and the words `肏` and `屄` are never taught in China, so most people do not use or cannot read these two words. The phrase is almost always passed down orally, so much so that it is often written incorrectly as `操他妈的逼。`

Comment: I'd rather say "it's often written intentionally (as opposed to incorrectly) as..." though I did meet people who pronounced 肏 as 入肉.

Answer (score 0):

Because "mother" is used for insult in Chinese.

Mandarin Examples of f-words:

> 肏你妈 [cào nǐ mā] Fuck your mom
>
> 你妈屄 [nǐ mā bī] Your mom's cunt.
>
> 肏你妈的屄 [cào nǐ mā de bī] Fuck your mom's cunt

Sometimes people just omit the f-words and use the "mom" only, such as

> 你妈的  [nǐ mā de]  your mom's
>
> 他妈的  [tā mā de]  his mom's